# Validation for new attribute on customer signup controller

Tags: magento2, customer, validation, registration

I have created new attribute 'customer_interest' and successfully getting it in form, frontend validation is working.

Now I need to validate it on backend(php), which file I need to work on? where is this signup form submitting?

Comment: please explain which type of validation you want?

Comment: I want to check if it is empty, then I will through error that this field is required